# How to delete or re-schedule a job?

Tags: java, servlets, scheduled-tasks, quartz-scheduler

Please have a look at the below code

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package RemindeWorker.Listener;


import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import static org.quartz.CronScheduleBuilder.dailyAtHourAndMinute;
import static org.quartz.JobBuilder.newJob;
import org.quartz.JobDetail;
import org.quartz.Scheduler;
import org.quartz.SchedulerException;
import org.quartz.Trigger;
import static org.quartz.TriggerBuilder.newTrigger;
import static org.quartz.TriggerKey.triggerKey;
import org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory;

/**
 *
 * @author Yohan
 */
public class ReminderExecuter extends ReminderCommon
{
    private static ReminderExecuter r;

    private ReminderExecuter()
    {
        super();
    }

    public static ReminderExecuter  getReminderExecuter()
    {
        if(r==null)
        {
            r = new ReminderExecuter();
        }

        return r;
    }

    public void executeRemnders()
    {
        passportReminder1();
       // passportReminder2();
    }

    private void passportReminder1()
    {
        String[] reminderTime = getFirstReminderTime().trim().split(":");
        String reminderHour = reminderTime[0];
        String reminderMinute = reminderTime[1];

        String[]reminderTime2 = getSecondReminderTime().trim().split(":");
        String reminderHour2 = reminderTime2[0];
        String reminderMinute2 = reminderTime2[1];

        System.out.println("Reminder Hour: "+reminderHour);
        System.out.println("Reminder Minute: "+reminderMinute);

        JobDetail job = newJob(PassportJob.class).withIdentity("passportJob1")
                .usingJobData("userName", getUserName())
                .usingJobData("password",getPassword())
                .usingJobData("host",getHost())

                .build();

         Trigger trigger = newTrigger()
                 .withIdentity(triggerKey("passportTrigger1", "passportTriggerGroup1"))
                 .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(Integer.parseInt(reminderHour), Integer.parseInt(reminderMinute)))
                 .startAt(new Date()).build();

         Trigger trigger2 = newTrigger()
                 .withIdentity(triggerKey("passportTrigger2", "passportTriggerGroup2"))
                 .withSchedule(dailyAtHourAndMinute(Integer.parseInt(reminderHour2), Integer.parseInt(reminderMinute2)))
                 .startAt(new Date()).build();

        try {
            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.start();
            scheduler.scheduleJob(job, trigger);
            System.out.println("Job 1 Scheduled");

            Scheduler scheduler2 = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler2.start();
            scheduler2.scheduleJob(job, trigger2);
            System.out.println("Job 2 Scheduled");

        } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    private void deleteJob()
    {
        try {
            Scheduler scheduler = new StdSchedulerFactory().getScheduler();
            scheduler.deleteJob(null);

        } catch (SchedulerException ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Here I created the `deleteJob()` method to delete and re-open or re-schedule the jobs listed in `passportReminder1()`. However I have no idea about how to it. Hw can I delete or re-schedule a quartz job? I am using the quartz 2 API.

Answer (score 3):

We can do in 2 ways:

1. Manually kill job and start again
2. use the code below:

> scheduler.deleteJob(new JobKey(jobData.getJobName()));

Refer [link](https://xebiaww.wordpress.com/2012/06/14/create-update-and-delete-jobs-dynamically-in-quartz/) for more details.

what you are trying to do it to delete a new job which is not useful.

You can edit your deleteJob() like below and call it when required:

```
   private void deleteJob(Scheduler scheduler, String jobName)
    {
        try {
            
            scheduler.deleteJob(new JobKey(jobName));

        } catch (Exception ex) {
            System.out.println(ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Your code is incomplete and I am unable to understand it properly.

Comment: Thanks. what is job name here? `passportJob1` ?

Comment: Yes. But there is an issue. That is, in your linked example, that person is first listing all the jobs. Here I can't pass the schedule, because it will simple delete the job which is scheduled "just now"

Comment: Thats whats you want i think from your post, just delete and re-schedule the job right? and if you cant send scheduler then you have to list and fetch and then send it as done in the example